# Dataframe data to float format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Привет, есть код:

```
kucoin = requests.get('https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/tick')

kuc = pd.DataFrame(kucoin.json()['data']).sort_values(['symbol'])

b = kuc.loc[kuc['symbol'].isin(pairskucbtc), ['sell']].to_string(index=False, header=None)
```

Данные выдаются в str формате, нужен float для арифметических расчетов.
Как конвертировать?
Я пробовал добавлять

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.8f}'.format
```

или

```
to_string(index=False, header=None, float.format=True)
```

Но тип данных все равно остается str.
Вывод данных:

```
0.0234024
0.0234241
0.2523452
.
.
```

много строк. Вот все строки мне нужно сделать числами.
Вывод данных без to_string():

```
sell
189 0.00029322
197 0.00005053
136 0.11209140
258 0.00008497
```

С индексом и заголовком, которые мне не нужны.

Comment: Приведите небольшой (2-3 строки) пример того, что вы хотите увидеть на выходе... Вам нужен Series, NDArray, list или что-то еще?

Comment: просто уберите `.to_string()` ... ;)

Comment: Если убираю .to_string() , то вывод такой:

Comment: вы пояснили в вопросе что вам не нужно, но не объяснили что вам нужно. Вы можете привести пример того, что вы хотите получить в вопросе? Вам нужен список floats?

Comment: Ладно, в принципе, просто без .to string() получилось то, что я и хотел: список floats или список чисел, которые можно сложить с другим списком чисел. А индексы и headers не мешают

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя `.to_string()` вы преобразовали Pandas.Series в **единственную** строку.

Если вам нужен список вещественных (`float`) значений:

```
In [55]: kuc.loc[kuc['symbol'].isin(['NEO-USDT','BTC-USDT']), ['sell']]
Out[55]:
           sell
1  11449.999998
6    127.500000

In [56]: kuc.loc[kuc['symbol'].isin(['NEO-USDT','BTC-USDT']), 'sell'].tolist()
Out[56]: [11449.999998, 127.5]
```

---

**Первоначальный ответ:**

Если я правильно понял вопрос и вас интересует значение **одной ячейки** в Pandas.DataFrame, то можно воспользоваться [DataFrame.at[...]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
In [35]: b = kuc.set_index('symbol').at['NEO-BTC', 'sell']

In [36]: b
Out[36]: 0.01117551

In [37]: type(b)
Out[37]: numpy.float64

In [38]: b * 100
Out[38]: 1.117551
```

Comment: нет, сейчас вопрос изменю